# actionscript3 function parameter modifier. Is it possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, parameters, actionscript

I tried to search about that, but didn't find anything. I used links to modify data via parameters in C++. In C#, for example, I can use like that:

```
bool foo(ref string r)
{
    r+= " is text";
}

bool bar()
{
    string s = "text";
    foo(ref s); // and now s == "text is text"
}
```

Is it possible to do it in actionscript3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-simulate-pass-by-reference-in-actionscript-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do that:

```
function foo(r:String):String {
    return r += " is text";
}

function bar():void {
    var s1:String = "text";
    var s2:String = foo(s1);
    trace(s2); // text is text
}
bar();
```

To illustrate what MasterRoro says, the same example with an `object` not belonging to the primitive data types and that is `passed by reference`:

```
function foo(r:Object):void {
    r.x += " is text";
}

function bar():void {
     var s:Object = {x:"text"};
     foo(s);
     trace(s.x); // text is text
}
bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this in AS3 without assigning a return value to the original variable like the previous poster said. If the parameter passed is a primitive data type (string, int, number, bool, etc.), it's going to be a copy as opposed to a reference. So changing it in the function body won't change it outside.

```
function foo(r:String):void{
   r += 'is text';
} 

function bar():void{
    var s:String = "text";
    foo(s);  // s == "text"
}
```

Only arrays, objects, and such are passed as references. So a way to do this would be to manipulate the properties of an object. Or just use the return value.